# R Transform in SPSS Modeler 17.1

Tags: r, spss, spss-modeler

I am being able to reuse a previously written R code (on creating weight of evidence - WOE, information value - IV etc.), from within SPSS Modeler 17.1 - Written within R Transform node.
The output summaries, for example Variable wise WOE and IV etc. are being stored in two separate R data frames within that R code.
Is there a way to make them available within SPSS Modeler to do further analyses on them - say some basic SELECT node addition for var selection on WOE/IV thresholds?

Please note: I am aware that these WOE/IV summary R dataframes could be written back as .CSV files and then re-read within SPSS Modeler for further analyses, but, my particular questions is "Is there a way to directly access newly created R Data Frame (not modelerData/modelerDataModel) from SPSS Modeler's R Transform node?"

Thanks!
Dip

Answer (score 1):

you have to use modelerData<-cbind(df1,df2)
and then adjust your modelerDataModel as well to match the columns of modelerData